# Express files serving not redirecting correctly

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to serve files using nodejs express but it's not redirecting the pages to the root path correctly.

My folder structure is like this:
root/pages/index.html

When I visit my website it gives me a Not Found error, until I manually add /pages after it.

This is my current code:

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const db = require('knex')(config.database);
const fs = require('fs');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const edus = express();

fs.existsSync('./pages/custom' ) || fs.mkdirSync('./pages/custom');
fs.existsSync('./' + config.logsFolder) || fs.mkdirSync('./' + config.logsFolder);

edus.use(helmet());
edus.set('trust proxy', 1);

edus.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
edus.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
edus.enable('view cache');


edus.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
edus.use(bodyParser.json());


edus.use('/', express.static('./public'));
edus.use('/api', api);

for (let page of config.pages) {
    let root = './pages/';
    if (fs.existsSync(`./pages/custom/${page}.html`)) {
        root = './pages/custom/';
    }
    if (page === 'index') {
        edus.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.sendFile(`${page}.html`, { root: root }));
    } else {
        edus.get(`/${page}`, (req, res, next) => res.sendFile(`${page}.html`, { root: root }));
    }
}

edus.use((req, res, next) => res.status(404).sendFile('404.html', { root: './pages/error/' }));
edus.use((req, res, next) => res.status(500).sendFile('500.html', { root: './pages/error/' }));

edus.listen(config.port, () => console.log(`edus started on port ${config.port}`));
```

What I'd like to do is to have the files in `/pages/` such as `/index.html`, etc, to be served when visiting website.com directly and without having to see the `/pages` in the URL.

Comment: Incomplete info here.  What route do you expect to get hit when you go to the root of your web site?  Are you expecting an `index.html` to be served via your `express.static('./public')` route?  Or are you expecting a route you create from config.pages to be the matching route.  I don't think we can solve this without knowing more about what you expect to happen when you get the 404.  If you expect something from `config.pages` to be your route, then we need to know what's in there.  If you expect `express.static('./public')` to match it, then we need to know what's in `./public`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, sorry for that. I just expect `index.html` to be served via `express.static(./public') route.

Comment: Try `edus.use(express.static('./public'));`  it will anyhow default to root.

Comment: `edus.use((req, res, next) => res.status(404).sendFile('404.html', { root: './pages/error/' }))` looks like this will send 404 to every request on every route

Comment: @SanSolo - Only if no route before that handles the request - which is the whole point.

Comment: And, where is `index.html` that you want your `express.static()` route to handle?  You need to realize that we don't know what's in your file system or where things are in your file system and that's paramount to helping with `express.static()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 my `index.html` is in `/var/www/website/html/pages/index.html`

Comment: So, why do you think that `express.static('./public')` will find something in `/var/www/website/html/pages`?  There's no `/public` anywhere in that path.

Answer (score 0):

> My folder structure is like this: root/pages/index.html

But then yyou have: `edus.use('/', express.static('./public'));` which should be :
`edus.use('/', express.static('./pages'));`

Comment: @Hi There does this help? if yes, can you please mark this as the answer?